# Broadcasting Data to Socket.io Client

Tags: socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-socket.io

I'm trying to build a chat app that will allow customer service reps to chat with customers. I'm using Angular for the frontend, and NestJS for the server. It's early on, so I can make changes relatively easily, but this is what my idea was for getting the chat working:

The customer clicks "connect", and they're added to a list of customers on the server. Each customer gets a room created for them, where they're the only one in the room initially. The customer service rep should be able to see a list of customer rooms so that they can join that room and chat with the customer. The problem is that the admin gets the list of rooms when they join, but I am unsure how to broadcast to their client that a new customer was added. I also only want the list of customers to be emitted to the customer service reps, so I have an `isAdmin` flag being passed in to most of the actions on the chat gateway.

I used `client.emit()`, but the problem is that when that happens, the `isAdmin` flag seems to always be `false`/`null`, so an empty array is returned. I could just emit all the rooms to everyone, even the customers, but then not display those customers, but I don't like the idea of sending that back over the connection since it would list to average customers who else is waiting on the support chat line.

Are there any ideas that you have for this type of functionality? I have all users, customer and customer service rep, using one gateway, but maybe I should have them connect to separate gateways that share some state (like the list of user chat rooms)?

I'm not sure the best design for this, but I think if I can work this out, I can get customer service reps to join chat rooms with customers and they'll be able to chat back and forth with each other.

Comment: Where do you store the isAdmin flag?

Comment: I'm storing it in the map of users. The map's key is the client ID, so I have that as well, but when a new customer joins, I need to broadcast to all admin clients the customer list.

Comment: Each socket has a 'data' field, you can save the necessary data there, it's more convenient

Comment: That is great to know. But I'm still unsure how I broadcast to all the Sockets with data.isAdmin === true so that they see the updated list of customer users

Comment: Add all admins to a special room and broadcast only the information they need